# Extract processed CSS as property on VueJS component for run time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Is it possible to get the CSS for a Vue component, and attach it as a string to a component when building a library for use at runtime?

```
vue-cli-service build --mode production --target lib --name components src/index.ts
```

I currently achieve this for some custom js using a custom block:

*vue.config.js:*

```
...
 rules: [
      {
        resourceQuery: /blockType=client-script/,
        use: './client-script-block',
      },
   ],
},
...
```

*client-script-block.js:*

```
module.exports = async function () {

  return `export default function (Component) {
      Component.options.__client_script = ${JSON.stringify(this.resourcePath)};
    }`;
};
```

which then exposed the string in the Vue app that uses the library. But achieving the same thing with CSS doesn't seem to play ball.

Comment: You can send the CSS as string using the same client script block - and then in your component put a watcher on the given prop and insert the CSS string as a `<style>` block in the DOM.

Comment: the code css appears to be Js when you do this like it hasnt been processed

Comment: Then you can try to move the CSS out of the `vue` files and put it in a `css` file inside the `public` folder.

Comment: @JohnC Why do you need to access the CSS through a property?

Comment: We are generating static web pages from Vue components and during the generation process we want to take the CSS for each component that is used on the and put it in our CSS manager to ensure the page only has what is required.

Comment: If the component's CSS is bundled with the component as JavaScript, then you wouldn't need to explicitly do that yourself. The styles would just be loaded automatically with the component.

Comment: I wish it worked like that, but in the use case I have that isnt an option. I need to access the compiled styles via an attribute on the component

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this CSS Extraction modules from **VueLoader**, that extracts the CSS from specific file or files, and stores it in a custom file, that you could then load dynamically in runtime, like:

Install:

```
npm install -D mini-css-extract-plugin

    

// webpack.config.js
    var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  // other options...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
            ? 'vue-style-loader'
            : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // ... Vue Loader plugin omitted
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css'
    })
  ]
}
```

Reference: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/extract-css.html#webpack-4:

Another approach:

```
// webpack.config.js
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  // other options...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          extractCSS: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
  ]
}
```

Reference: https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html

Also here you have a complete guide for extracting the CSS from a SSR (Server Side Rendered) apps: https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#enabling-css-extraction

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't solve the issue and if it was as simple as reading the VueJs documentation we would have already got to the solution.